# How do you make the whole body/background flash colors with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, text, colors, smoothing

So, I know how to make a singular piece of text flash colors. Here is an example:

```
// List of colors
var spectrum = ['#f00', '#f66', '#969', '#00F', '#0FB53F'];
var cycle = spectrum.length - 1;
// Cycle speed
var speed = 50;
var i = 0;
window.setInterval(function () {
document.getElementById("WL").style.color = spectrum[i];
if (i < cycle) i++;
else i = 0;
}, speed);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kffho8ra/

But, how do I make that container or the whole body flash colors? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Like this [epilepsy warning] http://jsfiddle.net/kffho8ra/1/ ?

Comment: Thank you... that was what I wanted. Is there a way to make it smooth, like slowly transitioning through all the colors in the rainbow? This comment will probably go unnoticed but I want to know :)

Comment: "*…how do I make that container or the whole body flash colors?*" - reluctantly, one would hope.

Comment: I am laughing so hard right now

Comment: wow are we stepping back into the 90's?? Might as well go back one more decade and add disco balls too

Comment: http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/

Answer (score 0):

Solved with:

http://jsfiddle.net/kffho8ra/1/

```
var spectrum = ['#f00', '#f66', '#969', '#00F', '#0FB53F'];
var cycle = spectrum.length - 1;

var speed = 50;
var i = 0;
window.setInterval(function () {
document.body.style.backgroundColor = spectrum[i];
if (i < cycle) i++;
else i = 0;
}, speed);'
```